# what is wrong with my query in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

The following code does not work, but it does work when I convert it to the next code. Why?

```
select * ,count(*) over(partition by colour) as counts_by_colour
from bricks;
```

output:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

modified:

```
select b.* ,count(*) over(partition by colour) as counts_by_colour
from bricks b;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the way SQL works - nothing to do with APEX.

`select *` means select all columns from what follows. So...

```
select * from emp join dept;
```

...returns all columns from emp and all columns from dept.

You are not allowed to select anything else with `select *` - e.g. ...

```
select *, 'abc' from emp;
```

raises the same error you got.

However, you can use `select alias.*` to select all columns from one table/view in the query, and then you are also allowed to select other things:

```
select e.*, 'abc' from emp e;
```

or

```
select e.*, d.loc from emp e join dept d;
```

The "implicit" alias also works:

```
select emp.*, 'abc' from emp;
```